# How to use Functional $scope methods in HTML templates without using ng-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning angular for my next project, I am confused how to use a $scope variable (call the function) in my template file, all the example I could find use it with ng-click, or more general how to access business logic of the controller in templates views? for example I have this function

```
$scope.rows  = function(){
    var rowNumber;
    rowNumber = Math.floor($scope.itemNumber / 6);

    var rows = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < rowNumber; i++){
        rows.push('row'+ i);
        console.log(rows);
    }

    return rows;
};
```

I want to access this rows array which is getting dynamically generated in ng-repeat?

Comment: you can make a call to a ctrl function like so: {{callToMyFunction()}}. As long as your function is defined on the $scope. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Do you need to call it to get some values into the HTML? Or on page load?

Comment: pls see the modifications, if it clarifies the query?

Comment: in that case your var rows  should be $scope.rows, then in your view you can do ng-repeat="row in rows"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its easy, just use

```
<div ng-repeat="row in rows()">
   <span>{{ row }} </span>
</div>
```

here is more information about ng-repeat https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to mix your business logic with your markup. But if you want to perform some logic and use the result in your view to conditionally render some element, you can add a method to your scope and call that

```
$scope.isButtonVisible()
{
  return $scope.someProperty==$scopeanotherProperty;
}
```

now you can use it in your view

```
<button ng-show="isButtonVisible" >Save</button>
```

EDIT : As per the comment, If you want to use an array, simply do this

```
$scope.products=[];

   for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
        $scope.products( { name : 'row'+ i} );           
    }
```

now in your view,

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products>
  <h1>{{product.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: I want to access the $scope.rows array in ng-repeat, this is getting generated dynamically.